# Android Menu: How to dynamically change menu with condition in code

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to change an item in the OptionMenu, depending on if a selected name (from Spinner) in the Activity, I tried to use `invalidateOptionsmenu()` inside `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`
and then in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` set my condition, but I get an error:

`"java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem"`

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private long projectId;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       datasource = new StatementDataSource(this);
       datasource.open();

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //setting a spinner with simpleCursorAdapter
       ...
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
           projectId = id;
           //trigger OptionsMenu to recreate
           invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }
 }

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    private String phoneNumber = datasource.getPhoneNumber(projectId);
    //checking if selected name has a phone number in the database
    if (!phoneNumber.isEmpty()){ //values might be null or empty
        menu.findItem(R.id.callButton).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.callButton).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`. Just setting up `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` should work since it is called every time the menu is displayed. Are you trying to update the menu while inside the menu?

Comment: @BinaryJudy but I want to change this item dynamic depending on which Item I is selected in the `Spinner`

Comment: @E H You probably already know this, but from [Android Development](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29): "This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents." According to that you should be able to dynamically modify the menu, and the next time it's shown it will be what you wanted. The error doesn't seem to fit what you have shown. Can you provide more code and/or LogCat?

Comment: @ BinaryJudy You're right it worked, there was just a different problem, it was caused by `!phoneNumber.isEmpty()` which on some records was throwing a `NullPointerExceptioin` so I notice not to rely on `String.isEmpty()` I did  `datasource.getPhoneNumber(projectId) != null && !datasource.getPhoneNumber(projectId).isEmpty()` and everything is working good, Thx